# how can i add a button in android default music player or existing package

Tags: android, android-widget

i am using android music player in my project .When i am clicking a button in my application it will show the android default music player,for that i am using following code

```
    Intent intent;
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER),0);
```

Button which are created by me are placed in the bottom of the screen.In that one home button is there,but when the music player is launch thebuttons are not visible.
So i want a back button or home button in the music player.i dont know whether it is possible to add a button in the existing package.Now i am using  back button in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not possible.  You can't modify the UI of another application.

Answer (score 0):

The back-Button would be the normal solution.

You can't add a button in an installed app on your phone. If you realy need new buttons in the default Music Player, you can [download the Source Code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music), add what you like and compile it. But I'm not sure if this is what you'll want to do.

Comment: ok allright...is it possible to reduce the music player width and hieght...why i am asking means, my home button is in the bottom.Suppose that musicplayer's bottom length is reduced means,my home button will visible all the time right? just like "layoutmarginBottom" in the properties.